# Delete cell ipython 2.0

Tags: python, keyboard-shortcuts, ipython

There is probably a very easy solution to this but I'm not sure what it is. Delete cell command in IPython 1.2 used to be:

```
ctrl-m d
```

according to the help menu in version 2.0 it says,

```
Shift-d: delete cell(press twice)
```

I've tried holding `shift` then pressing `d` twice and various combinations with `shift` and `d` and nothing seems to work.. Am I just doing this wrong or the command is actually not working? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

In the new IPython cells could have two states: when it has a green selection rectangle around it you can edit what's inside; when it has a grey rectangle around it you edit the cell itself (copy/paste/delete). Enter/Return makes it go green, Esc makes it go grey. When it is gray, 'dd' will delete it.

Comment: Turns out that Vimium overrides this command and prevents it from working, for those who encounter this issue in the future!

Comment: This `dd` shortcut worked out to me, however cell selection's color is blue nowadays

Answer (score 31):

To delete a cell, just click on the part margin part of the cell, the part that is not code or output ( right below the Ln[7]: in the picture below), and simply press the `d` key twice. Clicking there selects the entire cell and allows you to use keyboard short cuts like delete and or create a cell above or below.

[image]

Comment: Oh okay great. This is actually not a bad feature since I would have to click inside the cell anyways to use ctrl-m d

Comment: interesting. So why does the documentation say "shift"?

Comment: At least in version 3, nowhere it mentions shift. Just d + d. Also I found out that if you just press and hold d then your cells will start deleting and you can't undo but only the last deleted cell by pressing z.